# I want to display the corresponding letter of the number from the txt file called scores

Tags: python, function, text-files, python-3.6, user-input

So What I have done here, was to open the text file scores, strip,
replace('\n,'') and then read the lines of the text file into the scores
variable list(the output is below in scores). I am attempting to then split
each line in scores and place the first item in the line to letter and the
second item will be casted in score as an integer. I then want to test my
function to take an input of a letter from the user and then output its
corresponding score.

```
    def getLetterScore():
with open("scores","r") as file:
    scores = [[line.strip().replace('\n','') for line in file.readlines()]]
    letters_to_points = []
    for line in scores:
        line = line.split()
        letter = line[0]
        score = int(line[1])
        letters_to_points.append([letter,score])
        scores.close
    letter = input("Enter a letter: ")
    for item in scores:
        if item[0]==letter.upper():
            print("The corresponding score is:",(item[1]))

  updated code:
 def getletterscore():
    with open("scores","r") as file:
        Scores = [line.strip().replace('\n','') for line in 
file.readlines()]
letters_to_scores = []
for line in Scores:
    print(line)
    line = line.split("")
    letter = line[0]
    score = int(line[1])
    letters_to_scores.append([letter,score])
```

letter = input("Enter a letter: ")
for item in letter_to_scores:
if item[0]==letter.upper():
print("The corresponding score is:",(item[1]))

However, their is no output printed from this body of code. The complier skips
of the code to the next line.Any ideas what the issue with my code could be?

update = I have updated the code above but I am still having issues with the output it only starts me to enter a value when i remove the def getletterscore and the output from the inputed letter I enter doesnt matter as it prints in order.

```
scores = ['A 1', 'B 3', 'C 5', 'D 3', 'E 1', 'F 5', 'G 4', 'H 3', 'I 1', 'J 
10', 'K 8', 'L 3', 'M 5', 'N 3', 'O 2', 'P 5', 'Q 20', 'R 3', 'S 3', 'T 2', 'U 
1', 'V 10', 'W 12', 'X 16', 'Y 8', 'Z 20']
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure you have run your code?

Since you've made this into a function you need to make sure you call `getLetterScore()` somewhere after you define the function.

However, that will not be the end of the story there are still a couple of issues within the code.

One thing I would recommend with projects like this is to just add a bunch print statements everywhere just to get a better idea of what is happening such as:

```
def getLetterScore():
    with open("scores","r") as file:
        scores = [[line.strip().replace('\n','') for line in file.readlines()]]
        # lets see what kind of data we have in scores
        print(scores)

        letters_to_points = []
        for line in scores:
            # lets have a look over what we are iterating over
            print(line)

            line = line.split()
            letter = line[0]
            score = int(line[1])
            letters_to_points.append([letter,score])
            scores.close
        letter = input("Enter a letter: ")
        for item in scores:
            if item[0]==letter.upper():
                print("The corresponding score is:",(item[1]))

getLetterScore() # <- remember you need to call this!
```

With this it should make it easier to debug your code and see where the issue(s) are.

Lets assume we have a file:

```
A 1
B 2
C 3
```

if we run the code we get:

```
[['A 1', 'B 2', 'C 4']]
['A 1', 'B 2', 'C 4']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack.py", line 20, in <module>
    getLetterScore()
  File "stack.py", line 9, in getLetterScore
    line = line.split()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Lets try and break this down step by step.

The first line `[['A 1', 'B 2', 'C 4']]` shows us that the `scores` variable is actually a list of lists. So when we do:

```
for line in scores: 
    print(line)
```

we only get one print statement with the value `['A 1', 'B 2', 'C 4']`

this immediately explains the issue that we have with `line = line.split()` as we are trying to split a list as opposed to a string.

So how do we fix this?

`scores = [line.strip().replace('\n','') for line in file.readlines()]`

is the correct way of doing list comprehensions for a flat list.

Making this change and rerunning the code we get new output:

```
['A 1', 'B 2', 'C 4']
A 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack.py", line 20, in <module>
    getLetterScore()
  File "stack.py", line 13, in getLetterScore
    scores.close
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'close'
```

Now the line `scores.close` is wrong for several reason:

1. you can not close a list
2. if you wanted to close the file you opened you would need to do `file.close()` (note the brackets since it is a **method** not an attribute)
3. using the context manager removes the need to close files

What I mean with this last point is that without the `with` statement, you would have to do:

```
file = open('scores')

# ... do stuff to file

file.close() # at the end of using the file
```

but the with statements automatically does this for you:

```
with open('scores') as f: 
    # ... do stuff to file

# here the file is automatically closed
```

Basically we can just remove the `scores.close` line

Now if we run the code....

```
['A 1', 'B 2', 'C 4']
A 1
B 2
C 4
Enter a letter:a
a
The corresponding score is:
```

We dont get any output.

The reason is because you are iterating over `scores` and not `letters_to_points` so replacing this in the 3rd to last line you get the code that you want.

Comment: Is their any suggestions you can give, I'm still having the same issues as I don't really know where I went wrong in my code.

Comment: issues with my code are here :line = line.split()
    letter = line[0]
    score = int(line[1])
    letters_to_points.append([letter,score])
    scores.close
letter = input("Enter a letter: ")
for item in scores:
    if item[0]==letter.upper():
                print("The corresponding score is:"getletterscore(letter))

Comment: The output I get is that letter_to_points is not defined

Comment: Please take a look a my updated code in the body, Im still having issues with it. it only starts to work when i remove the def getletterscore and even at that. When I enter my input, it prints the score in order regardless of my input example Enter a letter: A
B 3
Enter a letter: B
C 5
Enter a letter: C
D 3
Enter a letter: D
E 1
Enter a letter: D
F 5

Comment: the first point is because you still need to call the function `getLetterScore()` after you define the function, the second point is because the line `letter = input(...)` should be at the same indentation level as `for item in letters_to_points:` eg:

Comment: how would I call the function in this situation please, i'm quite new to programming. The code just doesn't seem to be working at all. I have indented but confused on how to call the function

Comment: The main issue after i called the function print(getletterscore(item[1])) is that I keep getting a NameError: name 'Scores' is not defined

Comment: could you update your code with the correct indentation above?

Comment: Yes I have updated my code, The indentations are of that is because its hard to upload it.